# Dapper or MySql not finding stored procedures that contain a full stop "."

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, dapper

I've got a simple c# console that uses the Dapper ORM to make a call to a local MySql database in order to execute a stored procedure called `users.UserCreate`.

However, when running the query I get an exception saying

> Procedure or function 'UserCreate' cannot be found in database 'users'

But `users` isn't the database `local_db` is.

Here an example use:

```
public virtual Task CreateAsync(User user)
{
        using (var con = new MySqlConnection(_dbConn))
            return con.ExecuteAsync("users.UserCreate", user, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

_dbConn contains the connection string, also stating the name of the database as `local_db`.

This is what the stored procedure looks like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `users.UserCreate`(IN `@UserId` VARCHAR(128), IN `@UserName` VARCHAR(255), IN `@PasswordHash` LONGTEXT, IN `@SecurityStamp` LONGTEXT)
    NO SQL
INSERT INTO Users
(Id, UserName, PasswordHash, SecurityStamp, EmailConfirmed, PhoneNumberConfirmed, TwoFactorEnabled, LockoutEnabled, DateCreated, DateUpdated, IsDeleted)
VALUES
(@UserId, @UserName, @PasswordHash, @SecurityStamp, 0, 0, 0, 0, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE, 0)$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Is the problem something to do with MySql or Dapper? I use a similar naming convention for stored procedures in SQL Server, also using Dapper, and haven't had this problem before.

I have tried:

- Using "local_db.users.UserCreate"
- Using "local_db.UserCreate"
- Using "UserCreate"

Any ideas?

Comment: `con.ExecuteAsync(\`users.UserCreate\`…` ?

Comment: I think that escaping the procedure name will do the trick. Try to write ```users.UserCreate``` the `` will indicate the string is a singular identifier.

Comment: I just get an "unexpected character" error in visual studio if I just wrap the name in `users.UserCreate` with the `` identifiers. Also tried "`users.UserCreate`" with them wrapped in quotes (got rid of the VS error) and also @"`users.UserCreate`" and @"users.UserCreate". Still no joy

Comment: For the record: dapper makes absolutely no attempt to parse this query in any way; if you can find the syntax for calling a sproc in a specific schema in mysql, then: it should just work for dapper. I can't tell you what the specific syntax is, though, as I don't use mysql; with sql-server, I would expect `SprocName` (default schema for the connection), `schema.SprocName` or `[schema].SprocName` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out conversion from using SQL to MySQL has been full of learning curves in terms of MySQL's (in)capabilities. To get around the schema naming conventions using full-stops/periods (".") I've just replaced it with an underscore instead.

For anyone else facing the same dilemma, use underscores, you'll save yourself hours of headaches in the long run!

Comment: Schemas aren't naming conventions. The schema is not part of the stored procedure name, it's the location of the stored procedure, just like the server and database names