# function or Stored procedure does not exists in Database MySQL MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have created one new Stored proc in mysql DB, i am not sure why i am getting error "**Procedure or function '`test`' cannot be found in database '`dbname`'**."

I have searched the issue, found some article saying, it is because of DB name not in small letters etc, I have checked everything, there is no such type of issue,

I am bit strange, there I have some more stored proc, which are working fine. having the problem with newly created SPs. Not getting what I am missing. please help me.

**UPDATE:**

even i have created a simple SP as below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
    select 333;
END
```

C# code is:

```
 var ttt = db.Query<int>("test", commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am using Dapper.

facing same error.

[image: Here you can see, i have checked on workbench]

Comment: "having the problem with newly created SPs" does that mean calling older (existing) procedures in the same schema from the same code succeeds? please show DDL and calling code too.

Comment: does the procedure show up in workbench? does it need a schema prefix maybe?

Comment: Have you Checked that the SP does exist in the database? Have you tried calling the SP from the workbench or command line? If it doesn't exist or you get an error trying to call it - then we can rule out the C# code.

Comment: @PaulF, check the image i have added from workbench, it exists and is executing from workbench

Comment: See this - it maybe that you need to call bjj.test or bjj_test (note underscore, not dot/period) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42007894/dapper-or-mysql-not-finding-stored-procedures-that-contain-a-full-stop

Comment: if workbench requires bjj as a prefix, dapper probably will need to pass it too. use the fully qualified procedure name in the `Query` constructor.

Comment: @dlatikay, i have checked without fully qualified name, just used call test(); its working on workbench

Comment: I am not sure, what does it mean but, i have checked the Stored proc with definer root@% are accessible not root@localhost.

Comment: Maybe an access permission issue - you can check what permissions are set by running _"show grants for 'root'@'%';"_ and _"show grants for 'root'@'localhost';"_

Comment: @PaulF  -- for Localhost
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
-------- for root
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `bjj`.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: @PaulF, i am not sure, if these are same or not, i don't have much exp. in MYSQL. Please suggest, if i have to update anything

Comment: The permissions look OK. If you are saying that you can call the Stored procedure when DEFINER='root'@'%' - then why not do that - all that is changing is the actual user account that the SP is running under. Read up on MySQL SP security here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-security.html & here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: It could be caused by this Connector/NET bug that treats stored procedure names case-sensitively: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the code and Stored proc, nothing to do with MYSQL user permission. I created a new application to verify the same and access the SP there. it's working fine. then I tried to update the version of MYSQL connector that works for me. That's all.

Hope it will help in future. :)